# Aggregating postgresql rows by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have records with values like: date, hour, value. Aggregating whole day is easy, i just group by date. My problem is that i need to aggregate records from whole days with specific start/end time. In example when start time is 9 a.m. then i have records:
- from monday 9 a.m. to tuesday 8 a.m (grouped in one record)
- from tuesday 9 a.m. to wednesday 8 a.m. (grouped in one record)
and so on.
Thanks, for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume your hour field is an INT, but regardless you should be able to adapt this...

```
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN hour >= 9 THEN date ELSE date - 1 END
```

This essentially treats any hour before 9am as being part of the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY date_trunc('day',date+(hour-9)*interval '1h')` or something like that?